# Haskell : A function that updates a state by calculating with each value of a list

Tags: list, function, haskell

I need a function that updates a state multiple times depending on a list of values: for each value of the list it may possibly update the state or leave it unchanged. So I figured I'd need a function of a type like:

```
[a] -> b -> (a->b->b) -> b
```

Where [a] is a list of values for which goes that for each of them the state b may be updated (depending of the value of a). Then the resulting b is a new state that has all necessary updates applied.

However I could not find any function that on Hoogle that does this, so I figure I'd have to make one myself however I have no idea how I could do this. Are there any functions existing that I can use to accomplish such function?

If anyone could help me out on this it'd be much appreciated!

Best regards,
Skyfe.

EDIT: A (simplified) example of what I could have & need:

```
[a] = [1, 5, 3, 6]
b   = State{x, y, z}
f :: (a->b->b)
f a b = if someAlgorithm a then b{x=someFunc x, y=y+1} else b
```

=> Then the function I need should execute f on all a's and for each time it does so, it should return the new (updated or unchanged) b as argument for the new call to f along with the next element from the list [a], and so on untill it has done this for all elements and results into a final b with all updates applied.

Comment: This looks very much like a fold...

Comment: What do you mean you couldn't find it on hoogle? This is foldr with flipped around parameters.

Comment: `foldr :: (a -> b -> b) -> b -> [a] -> b`

Comment: Yes but it doesn't do what I need it to do: how would I use fold to update one state multiple times depending on the outcomes of a function for each of the items in the list (and for each of them the (new) state may be updated)? It could simply execute a function on a list of items to merge them together but I wouldn't be able to use it for the purpose I need (or I may not be seeing something clearly).

Comment: @user2999349 You'll have to explain more clearly what you mean then. There's only two functions satisfying your type signature, one is foldr and the other is just returning the b you gave it at first.

Comment: disregard that (or change it to "sensible functions". There are actually also weird functions that don't apply the passed function to certain parts of the list that I didn't think of earlier)

Comment: @Cubic I've added a simplified example, I hope it's makes it more clear.

Comment: What does `b{a=someFunc a, b=b+1}` mean in the `then` part of your `if`? I understand this is supposed to be pseudocode and not Haskell, per se, but what are you trying to do?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I just noticed I used b as two different types, but it means: update the values of a and b inside of the state b (should be named differently, e.g. s).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is `foldr f b a` after applying `filter someAlgorithm` on your list. If you don't know these functions, look them up on hoogle.

Comment: That sounds sensible, I think I was too close-minded when it came to using foldr, I thought of it as only useable for merging lists with operators. I'll try this and see if it works properly, thanks!

Comment: A quibble: Depending on which direction you want to go through the list, `foldl'` might fit better than `foldr`.